Wave equation, partial differential equation formulation
I want to formulate the problem of partial differential equation into a mathematical form.

Suppose a string of length $L$ is tied to both ends. Then the string
is released from rest with initial displacement $f(x)$.

The situation is fit to be a wave equation, which a second order partial differential equation.
Let $u(x,t)$ denotes the measure of disturbance. Then by the given condition:
$$u(x,0)=f(x)=\text{initial displacement}, \\ ~\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0,~\text{since released from rest}.$$
Using Hooke's law and Newton third law and using finite difference method, the wave equation derived to be in its usual form as follows:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},$$ where $c$ denotes the speed of wave.
Therefore the ultimate mathematical problem  is as follows:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},$$
such that
$$u(x,0)=f(x) \\ ~\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0$$
Is this correct?

Yes, that is correct.
